# Next autogenerated ID failing for no reason? ISNULL(MAX(IdDWUpdate),0)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have a SQL server 2008 and SSIS package that has been running perfectly so far (year or so). Starting a few days ago, it stops on error:

```
Description: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'InvoiceIdDW', table 'Test2.dbo.Payments'; 
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

However the part of the script that it fails on has worked and it should handle NULLs by giving out 0 on NULL values. The script has not been altered since it was run successfully the last time

```
INSERT INTO [Testi2].[dbo].[Payments]
           ([PaymentId]
           ,[PaymentsArchiveId]
           ,[SourceSystemIdDW]
           ,[PaymentType]
           ,[InvoiceIdDW]
           ,[PaymentVoucherId]
           ,[PaymentDate]
           ,[PaymentAmount]
           ,[CurrencyCode]
           ,[PaymentAmountCurrency])
SELECT SuLasNro , SuArkTunn , 1 , SuLaji , ISNULL(h.InvoiceIdDW,0) , s.SuTosNro , s.SuPvm , s.SuMk , s.SuValKdi , s.SuVal
FROM Latausalue.dbo.Tikon_suoritukset s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Testi2.dbo.Company c ON c.SourceSystemIdDW = 1 AND c.CompanyId = s.yritys
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Testi2.dbo.InvoiceHeader h ON h.InvoiceId = s.SuLasNro AND h.CompanyIdDW = c.CompanyIdDW AND h.OrigKey_1 = s.SuAsTunn AND h.OrigKey_2 = s.SuSVTili AND h.SourceSystemIdDW = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  s.invoicepayment_id , s.invoicepayment_archive , 3 , 'M' , h.InvoiceIdDW , '' , s.invoicepayment_date , 
        s.invoicepayment_total , s.invoicepayment_account_currency , s.invoicepayment_total_incurrency
FROM Latausalue.dbo.Lemon_suoritukset s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Testi2.dbo.Company c ON c.SourceSystemIdDW = 3 AND c.CompanyId = RIGHT('0000' + s.yritys,4)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Testi2.dbo.InvoiceHeader h ON h.InvoiceId = s.invoice_id AND h.CompanyIdDW = c.CompanyIdDW AND h.SourceSystemIdDW = 3
WHERE h.InvoiceIdDW IS NULL
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: I believe it shoud work. What is the result if you execute `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(IdDWUpdate),0) FROM Latausalue.dbo.Loki_DWUpdate` But if MAX(IdDWUpdate) is NULL, there are no rows in the table, right? Why insert a row then?

Comment: Every other row should have values, the script is used to clean out old stuff and bring a newer version of the data. That is the only part mysteriously crashing

Comment: Looking at the error, why do you believe this is the part that fails? It says Table Test2.dbo.Payments?

Comment: this part might be more relevant actually, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Well, that's exactly where it goes wrong: `WHERE h.InvoiceIdDW IS NULL` in the second `SELECT`. And there's no `ISNULL` around `h.InvoiceIdDW`, only in the first `SELECT`.

Comment: Can you check whether [Testi2].[dbo].[Payments] got added with a column recently which is not in the INSERT list, with the column set NOT NULL.

Comment: Where's the `ISNULL(MAX(IdDWUpdate),0)` bit sitting at?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason for issue is 'select' statement after UNION ALL as @NickyvV mentioned.

```
SELECT  s.invoicepayment_id , s.invoicepayment_archive , 3 , 'M' , h.InvoiceIdDW
```

More over, there stands a condition:

```
 WHERE h.InvoiceIdDW IS NULL
```

You can never rely that package 1-year 'no problem' production means that everything is OK.
Always be prepared :)